# Using Gtk.Builder with Gtk.Application

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I have a window in my window.ui (created with glade), and I should to add a application property like this:

```py
win = SchoolnotebookWindow(application=self)
```

But, I can't add application property to window, because window is in my UI file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [win.set_application(self)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-application). This can be done after the Gtk.ApplicationWindow is loaded from Glade.